# Not giving expected result after migration Sonar to SonarQube 4.0

Tags: sonarqube

I have recently migrated the Sonar to SonarQube 4.0. Everything looks OK to me except one field Unit Tests Coverage result. Here it is showing dash (-) in the result. But the expected result would be like 0.0% . Provided both the result. Please let me know the solution to fix this error.

Current result :

```
   Unit Tests Coverage

    -
```

Expected Result :

```
   Unit Tests Coverage

    0.0% 

    0.0% line coverage 

    0.0% branch coverage
```

Comment: If possible, please provide the output of the analysis job, this could indicate why the coverage data is not taken into account.

Comment: Please mention for which language you are doing analysis